# Galois theory theorem proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter6.pdf

This is taken from Robert Ash Abstract Algebra chapter 6 Galois theory.

In section $6.1.3$, first sentence, how do we know the cardinality of $G$ is finite? Is it always true that $|G|$ is always finite?

Answer (score 3):

Any element of $G$ is determined by its effects on the finitely many elements of a vector space basis $\alpha_1,\ldots ,\alpha_d$ of $E$ over $F$ and each of these is algebraic, hence can only be mapped to finitely many candidates (namely the other roots of the irrducible polynomial $f_j(X)\in F[X]$ for $\alpha_j$)